# update frequency of MySQL tables

Tags: mysql

In information_schema.TABLES the update_time stores the date of the last update of a table, but no information is about the update frequency.
What if I want to know how many times a table is updated in a day/month?

Comment: You could create a trigger on the table that, at each update, creates a row in a dedicated log table with a timestamp, and then query that table.

Comment: I would like some sort of metadata, because I want to do this on all the tables, even on those still to be created. Can I retrieve this information from logs?